# Create a view with identical columns

Tags: sql, view, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE `matchs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `player_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_2` int(11) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE `score` (
  `id_matchs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to create a view in order to get something like this :

```
|img_p1|name_p1|score_p1|score_p2|name_p2|img_p1|
+------+-------+--------+--------+-------+------+
|      |       |        |        |       |      |
|      |       |        |        |       |      |
```

But I don't really know where to start as there are 2 identical columns for img, name and score.

EDIT:

So I have been able to solve the problem thanks to mdem7. Here is the code:

```
SELECT p1.img, p1.name, s1.score, s2.score, p2.nom, p2.img
FROM player p1, player p2, matches m, score s1, score s2
WHERE p1.id = s1.id_player AND m.id = s1.id_matchs AND p2.id = s2.id_player
AND m.id = s2.id_matchs AND m.player_1 = p1.id AND m.player_2 = j2.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in your example, you need to `alias` the column names

The following is the not the complete SQL because limited info given, but
you can play with it to create your own.

```
select p1.img as img_p1, p1.name as name_p1, s1.score as score_p1,
       s2.score as score_p2, p2.name as name_p2, p2.img as img_p2
from player p1, player p2, matches m1, matches m2, scores s1, scores s2
where p1.id = s1.id_player and m1.id = s1.id_matches
      p2.id = s2.id_player and m2.id = s2.id_matches
...
```

Comment: When I try to do your query I get this error: 
`#1054 - Field 'p1.score' unknown in field list` 

I guess get it because score is in the score table instead of player. 

So I removed the alias from `SELECT p1.score and p2.score` and I get this error instead: 
`#1052 - Field:'score' in field list is ambiguous`

I guess it comes from the fact that there is 2 score in the select `SELECT p1.img, p1.name, score, score, p2.nom, p2.img`

Comment: I have fixed the SQL to refer score from score table, check and let me know.